# Wampserver: DocumentRoot in OneDrive

Tags: windows-8.1, wampserver, onedrive

I hope someone can help me to solve the following, probably technical, problem.

I use wampserver on my desktop with windows 7, with the documentroot in the OneDrive folder. That works perfectly. Through OneDrive, I synchronize the files in the documentroot with another computer.

Now I want to do the same on my tablet, running windows 8.1. I installed a new version of wamp. As installed, everything works fine. Now I want to change the directoryroot to a folder in OneDrive. So I adapted the file httpd.conf on two places:

DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
becomes
DocumentRoot "c:/Users/Fred Simons/OneDrive/WWW/"

and

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
becomes
<Directory "c:/Users/Fred Simons/OneDrive/WWW/">

After restarting the tablet, the wampserver icon is orange or red, Im am not sure. Clicking on localhost opens the browser, but it shows the message: cannot connect to the server at localhost.

As already mentioned, the same construction works fine under windows 7. All files in OneDrive are available offline, so on the tablet they should be the true files and not dummies. It looks like a typo, but I do not see any.

Many thanks for looking at my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I arrived at a somewhat unsatisfactory conclusion: it seems that, under Windows 8.1, folders in OneDrive cannot be used inside the WAMP root directory. My question above is an example of that. Another experiment I did was to set back the root directory to the default c:/wamp/www and the place OneDrive within this root directory. All subfolders outside OneDrive could be used, but all attempts to include a file from OneDrive failed.

Under Windows 7, there is no problem in using OneDrive folders in the root directory.

Hopefully, it will be possible again under Windows 10.

Comment: @Steve This originally did not work because of how OneDrive on Windows 8/8.1 (I dont remember which) handled placeholders - for whatever reason, WAMP could not see directories that handled placeholders. Microsoft fixed the asker's issue by removing placeholder functionality, which extended to Win10 by default. However, in Windows 10 Insider Preview build 16212, placeholder functionality was restored under a new name: Files on Demand. This functionality has broken it again (imagine my surprise when Apache couldn't see my OneDrive-stored virtual hosts after upgrading).

Comment: This issue is still occurring today.  I had to setup my PHP server project directories outside of OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

If the wampmanager icon is not GREEN then one (or both ) of the services ( Apache(wampapache)/MySQL(wampmysqld) ) has not started properly.

First find out which service has not started.
Using the wampmanager menus do :-

```
wampmananager -> Apache -> Service
If the Start/Resume Service menu item is Green and clickable, then Apache has not started
```

So look at the Apache error log

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Apache error log
```

Then do

```
wampmananager -> MySQL -> Service
If the Start/Resume Service menu item is Green and clickable, then MySQL has not started
```

So look at the MySQL error log

```
wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL log
```

If either of these files does not exists, then the service failed before it could open these logs, so now you need to look at the Windows Event Viewer

```
Start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer
```

And look in the

```
Windows Logs -> Application' section accessed from the menu on the left of the dialog for error messages from Apache and or MySQL.
```

If Apache is the service that is not running it is normally, but not always, because something else has captured port 80.

Now do,
Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the menu-> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80
This will launch a command window and display some information about what, if anything is using port 80.

Whatever it is should be re-configured to not use port 80 or uninstalled if you are not using it.

Comment: Many thanks for your very clear instructions. It turned out that Apache is not working, no messages in the log file, but Event Viewer showed an error: Event ID 3299: DocumentRoot must be a directory. As far as I can see, the DocumentRoot I entered IS a directory, see my question. I changed the space in the directory name with \  and with _, without success. Is there anything else I can try? (Port 80 is available, and it works on windows 7)  Once again many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
unckeck the `on demand` option on the `OneDrive` Settings and select directories to sync. wait some minutes.

Comment: Onedrive 2023 has not this option :/ very well microsoft XD